# DNN: How to include .html template file into another .html template file

Tags: html, dotnetnuke

I searching for something similar to PHP code but for DNN template:

```
<div class="included">
    <?php include_once('another.html'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to include this in the HTML file, or in a Skin/Module?

Comment: @ChrisHammond in .html file inside a module

Comment: So you don't include HTML files in modules, you include ASCX Files in modules. I can document how you do that pretty easily

Comment: @ChrisHammond, Let me clarify, what I want to do... I making changes for News Article Module layout, I can make changes in their .ascx and .html (temlates or skins? for the module) files. So, I need to "call" one .html from another, i.e. include it instead of code duplication among files

Comment: You'll need to check with the module vendor to see if they support it, I highly doubt it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can offer a couple possible options:

1) Server-side if you have access to .ascx.

```
<asp:Literal ID="litNewsIncludes" runat="server" />
<%
   StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("~/Portals/0/includes/news.html");
   litNewsIncludes.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
   sr.Close();
%>
```

2) Client-side option using jquery ajax to load the html

```
<div id="divNewsIncludes"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#divNewsIncludes").load("/Portals/0/includes/news.html");
</script>
```

Comment: honestly, it's not exactly what I required, but these two options definitely help me to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="included">
<!--#include file="another.html"-->
</div>
```

The file in which you use this needs to be executable by ASP.NET, like a .asp or .aspx file.  If your file is a plain HTML file, you should be able to get away with changing the extension to .asp or .aspx.  The file you're pulling in can be anything, really (text, HTML, XML, etc.).

You may also need to enable server side includes in your IIS setup for this to work.

Comment: SSI is not available, it's why I'm asking. Probably, DNN has own way to include files?